# Django queryset not ordering correctly on production

Tags: django, django-models, sql-order-by, webfaction

I have a model:

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

class Entity(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

In my view I just want to obtain all the Entities and order them by the name of the client:

## views.py

```
def all_entities(request):
    entities = Entity.objects.all().order_by('client')
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'entities': entities})
```

And so my template just prints all the entities.

## template.html

```
<html>
{% for entity on entities %}
 {{ entity.client }}}
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

Happens is that in my development PC all works pretty good, I get a list of ordered client names, what I can't understand is that on my production server on webfaction.com the result is not ordered alphabetically as in my local environment.

I testes it on the shell too, results are the same, somehow order_by('client') is returning an alphabetically sorted list on my PC but not alphabetically ordered on production.

Notes: Both environments have Postgres and use the same backend.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to set the ordering by default to be by name, add `class Meta: ordering = ('name',)` to the `Person` model; otherwise check Yuji's answer.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: this was usefull too, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm not going to try to figure out *why* it appears to work for you, but I can't help but notice that the ORM wouldn't know **which field** to order by given a direct order to order by `client`.

It's probably just sorting by PK.

```
entities = Entity.objects.all().order_by('client__name') 
#                                               ^^^^^^ specify sort field
#                    I am addicted to carets
```

Comment: I thought it would sort on the __unicode__ method of Person, that's why I did it that way.

Comment: Right that makes sense, but the ordering is done at DB level!